# Connecting Arduino to Heroku web connected to Django database

Tags: api, http, heroku, https, arduino

**To describe my problem** I was trying to connect my **Arduino UNO** to website created by me in **Heroku**.

**Main purpose** was to called **rest api** function in **arduino conected to Internet** and get a **json data**.

*My Arduino code:*

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

  // Initialize Ethernet library
  byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
  Ethernet.init(8);  // use pin 53 for Ethernet CS

  if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
   Serial.println(F("Failed to configure Ethernet"));
   return;
  }
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(F("Connecting..."));

  // Connect to HTTP server
  EthernetClient client;
  client.setTimeout(10000);
  if (!client.connect("https://salty-cliffs-06856.herokuapp.com", 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("Connected!"));

  // Send HTTP request
  client.println(F("GET /api/command/ HTTP/1.1"));
  client.println(F("Host: https://salty-cliffs-06856.herokuapp.com"));
  client.println(F("Connection: close"));
  Serial.println(F("Done"));
  if (client.println() == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to send request"));
    return;
  }


  // Check HTTP status
  char status[32] = {0};
  client.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
  Serial.println(status);
  if (strcmp(status, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") != 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
    Serial.println(status);
    return;
  }

  // Skip HTTP headers
  char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
  if (!client.find(endOfHeaders)) {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid response"));
    return;
  }

  // Allocate JsonBuffer
  // Use arduinojson.org/assistant to compute the capacity.
  const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) + JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + 60;
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(capacity);

  // Parse JSON object
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(client);
  if (!root.success()) {
   Serial.println(F("Parsing failed!"));
   return;
  }

  // Extract values
  Serial.println(F("Response:"));
  Serial.println(root["command"].as<char*>());


  // Disconnect
  client.stop();
```

Everything was working fine with that code when I was trying putting there non-secured **HTTP** address. After putting there my web **powered by Heroku** secrued by **HTTPS** **I always got error**.

The program annouced error when I was **checking HTTP status** and in my Arduino port terminal I got response:

```
Unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I checked my heroku logs but there **are not listed any request from Arduino**. (Just to be sure I tried to called API from web browser and it works)

Could you help me where could be a problem ? I was thinking that it could be because of secured HTTPS. What do you think ?

**Thanks for every help :)**

Answer (score 0):

First, change `client.connect("https://salty-cliffs-06856.herokuapp.com", 80)` 
from

```
`https`
```

to

```
`http`
```

as port 80 is not `https` port and Ethernet shield does not support SSL.

Secondly, you have a wrong http header for `Host`. the HTTP 1.1 requires that only the domain name to use used without the protocol (i.e. http://) prefix. So change the line:

```
client.println(F("Host: https://salty-cliffs-06856.herokuapp.com"));
```

to:

```
client.println(F("Host: salty-cliffs-06856.herokuapp.com"));
```